# Trouble logging in to SQL2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently installed SQL2008 and am having trouble logging in from another application.  I have set the security to shared authentication and have specified a password for the SA login.  I am able to log in using SA and password from the management studio and also from command prompt using the osql command, but when trying to log in from third party software (specifically, WhereNet VSS) I get the popup "The SQL Instance Name or login information is not correct.  Please try again."

Any suggestions?  Unfortunately I cannot install the software until I can successfully log in to the SQL server so it is critical that I get past this ASAP.

Thanks,

Joseph

Comment: It might be worth sharing the full connection string (without the password:-) ).

Comment: This isn't programming related.

Comment: boo for using sa account.  you really should either be authenticating as a windows user or logging in as a sql login, not as sa.

Comment: I know, and I would gladly do that if it were an option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable remote connections to your SQL Svr instance (see Server Properties, Connections)? Also, make sure the Windows (or proprietary) firewall isn't interfering w/ connectivity.

Comment: Yes, shared pipes and TCP/IP have been enabled.  I also made sure that the IP addresses (In TCP/IP properties) were enabled and active.

I have disabled all firewalls (and disconnected from internet) but still cannot connect from software.  And let me clarify, the Software is installed on the Server Machine.

Comment: Any change if you use the IP addr instead of the host name?? (Grasping for straws...)

Answer (score 0):

Other than allowing remote connections from SQL Server Instance properties --> connections - did you configure remote connections from **SQL Server Surface Area Configuration** tool? If not you might wanna play with those options to enable remote connections over TCP/IP and/or named pipes.

Also - did you check from the **Configuration Manager Tool** if TCP/IP properties are properly configured (TCP port properly set, etc.)

Did you try to do the same stuff on another machine and see if with the same settings it works?

Comment: TCP\IP and Named pipes have been enabled through the SQL server configuration manager.  (There is no SQL Server Surface Area Configuration in SQL 2008).

Comment: Also tried using SQL2005 but same problems.  I did use Surface Area configuration and enabled all appropriate remote connections, but still nothing.

Comment: it is puzzling - did you try same setting on different machine? We also have a machine at work with the same problem that we cannot quite figure out - we kinda gave up!